# Experimenting with silent Install of SQL Server using a batch file

Tags: sql-server

I have saved following statement in a batch file to install SQL server express silently.

```
E:\UnInstall\SQLServer\sqlexpr.exe/Q/SAPWD="testpwd123"/security=SQL
```

When I run the batch file, I get error

> *The system can not find the path specified.*

While my `sqlexpr.exe` is in the given folder (`E:\uninsall\SQLServer`)

Please advise if something is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: So take the command out of the batch file and type it in at the command line. Starting in your sqlserver folder and work backwards. If the file is there, it's got to be an other problem hasn't it? PS I'd have expected a space before the /Q argument...

Answer (score 0):

Put a space between the filename and the `/Q` param:

```
E:\UnInstall\SQLServer\sqlexpr.exe /Q /SAPWD="testpwd123" /security=SQL
```